# action not called when adding a button to a scrollview

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview, uibutton

I have a strange behavior with my buttons that I add to a scrollview.

```
    for (UIView *subview in self.scrollView.subviews) {
        [subview removeFromSuperview];
    }
    //Create and place info Button(s)
    for (int i = 0; i < BigPictures.count; i++) {
        UIButton *infoButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(scrollView.frame.size.width*(i+1) - 29 - 5 - 10, scrollView.frame.size.height - 29 - 5, 29, 29)];
        [infoButton addTarget:self action:@selector(flip) forControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        //[infoButton setEnabled:YES];
        //[infoButton setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

        [self.scrollView addSubview:[FrontViews objectAtIndex:i]];
        [infoButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_image-info.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [scrollView addSubview:infoButton];
```

BigPictures contains all images I want to show in the scrollview.
Now to the odd thing. If BigPictures contains 1 image then the action (flip) is called. As soon as [BigPictures count] > 1 then the button on the first image is not executing the action but all other buttons (page 2-n) are. So how can this be??

Even if I change `for (int i = 0; i < BigPictures.count; i++)` with `for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)` then the button is working.

So what am I missing? Already tried things like

```
scrollView.delaysContentTouches = NO;
scrollView.canCancelContentTouches = NO;
```

but latter one disables scrolling of scrollview.

EDIT:
I tried placing other buttons at different positions and none of them work on the first page (if pages > 1). Also tried to place a GestureRecognizer. This works but `if ([touch.view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])` is not detecting a button underneath. All works fine on the other pages in scrollview. Really weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did a complete rebuild and now it works. Really strange because I used the exact same code.